# MongoDB Complex Aggregation - Combined Sum & Count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a DB in which each document has an array of many different objects, of which I'm interested in working with only 6 specific ones. 5 of which are integers and 1 is categorical (text).

In order to leave only the fields I need for the aggregation, I've used $unwind on the fields array - multiplying each document by the number of fields it has. After this I filtered the specific fields I want using a basic $match.

This is where I hit some trouble - I've managed to write two queries where each gives me half of the end result I need. But I'm unable to combine them together into one general query. Specifically, I have one query that gives me 5 integer fields, each is the $sum of each integer fields, and another query that uses the categorical field in order to $count the number of times each category appears.

**The desired output** would give me a single document that has 5 k:v fields (1 for each sum calculation), and an additional object that includes k:v fields (where each key is a category and the value is the number of times it appears. this must be its own object because the categories that appear may vary).

The sample data I've added has been striped of most of it's structure and includes only the crucial parts relevant for this query. This is in order to secure our clients privacy.

I've tried solving this from every angle I could think of - and would greatly appreciate any feedback!

The **first** query:

```
[{$match: {
     fields: {
      $elemMatch: {
       field_id: 174196148,
       'values.start': {
        $gte: ISODate('2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
        $lt: ISODate('2022-02-03T00:00:00.000Z')
       }
      }
     }
    }}, {$unwind: {
     path: '$fields'
    }}, {$match: {
     $or: [
      {
       'fields.field_id': 226577699
      },
      {
       'fields.field_id': 225330844
      },
      {
       'fields.field_id': 158472699
      },
      {
       'fields.field_id': 191195626
      },
      {
       'fields.field_id': 219444876
      }
     ]
    }}, {$unwind: {
     path: '$fields.values'
    }}, {$addFields: {
     'Specific - Field Value': {
      $round: [
       {
        $toDecimal: '$fields.values.value'
       }
      ]
     }
    }}, {$group: {
     _id: '$fields.label',
     SumCalculation: {
      $sum: {
       $toDecimal: '$Specific - Field Value'
      }
     }
    }}, {$group: {
     _id: null,
     SumArray: {
      $push: {
       k: '$_id',
       v: '$SumCalculation'
      }
     }
    }}, {$project: {
     _id: 0,
     Final: {
      $arrayToObject: '$SumArray'
     }
    }}]
```

The **second** query:

```
 [{$match: {
     fields: {
      $elemMatch: {
       field_id: 174196148,
       'values.start': {
        $gte: ISODate('2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
        $lt: ISODate('2022-03-31T00:00:00.000Z')
       }
      }
     }
    }}, {$unwind: {
     path: '$fields'
    }}, {$match: {
     'fields.field_id': 177278285
    }}, {$unwind: {
     path: '$fields.values'
    }}, {$group: {
     _id: '$fields.values.value.text',
     ModelCount: {
      $sum: 1
     }
    }}, {$group: {
     _id: null,
     Full: {
      $push: {
       k: '$_id',
       v: '$ModelCount'
      }
     }
    }}, {$project: {
     _id: 0,
     Final: {
      $arrayToObject: '$Full'
     }
    }}]
```

The desired output:

```
{
  "Final": {
    "Business Model": [
      {
        "K": "Solar Lease",
        "V": 3
      },
      {
        "K": "Solar Purchase",
        "V": 112
      }
    ],
    "System Size - Signed Contract": 73,
    "Additional Payment for O&M": 2000,
    "O&M Years Included (Paid)": 2,
    "Total Price Including VAT": 396660,
    "1st Milestone - Down Payment": 30280
  }
}
```

Sample data:

```
{
  "_id": 1946794344,
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "money",
      "field_id": 226577699,
      "label": "1st Milestone - Down Payment ",
      "values": [
        {
          "currency": "ILS",
          "value": "6120.0000"
        }
      ],
      "config": {
        "settings": {
          "allowed_currencies": [
            "ILS"
          ]
        },
        "mapping": null,
        "label": "1st Milestone - Down Payment "
      },
      "external_id": "1st-milestone-down-payment-2"
    },
    {
      "type": "money",
      "field_id": 225330844,
      "label": "Additional Payment for O&M",
      "values": [
        {
          "currency": "ILS",
          "value": "0.0000"
        }
      ],
      "config": {
        "settings": {
          "allowed_currencies": [
            "ILS"
          ]
        },
        "mapping": null,
        "label": "Additional Payment for O&M"
      },
      "external_id": "additional-payment-for-om"
    },
    {
      "type": "money",
      "field_id": 158472699,
      "label": "Total Price Including VAT",
      "values": [
        {
          "currency": "ILS",
          "value": "61270.0000"
        }
      ],
      "config": {
        "settings": {
          "allowed_currencies": [
            "ILS"
          ]
        },
        "mapping": null,
        "label": "Total Price Including VAT"
      },
      "external_id": "money"
    },
    {
      "type": "number",
      "field_id": 191195626,
      "label": "System Size - Signed Contract",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "11.6600"
        }
      ],
      "config": {
        "settings": {
          "decimals": 2
        },
        "mapping": null,
        "label": "System Size - Signed Contract"
      },
      "external_id": "hspq-hmrkt"
    },
    {
      "type": "number",
      "field_id": 219444876,
      "label": "O&M Years Included (Paid)",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "0.0000"
        }
      ],
      "config": {
        "settings": {
          "decimals": 0
        },
        "mapping": null,
        "label": "O&M Years Included (Paid)"
      },
      "external_id": "om-years-gifted-for-free"
    },
    {
      "type": "category",
      "field_id": 177278285,
      "label": "Business Model",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": {
            "status": "active",
            "text": "Solar Purchase",
            "id": 6,
            "color": "DCEBD8"
          }
        }
      ],
      "external_id": "mvdl-sqy"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can give us your sample data and the expected output too

Comment: Hey @ray, I've added both sample data and expected output. I'd love to hear your thoughts! Thanks

Comment: Your sampled data does not really produce any result with the provided 2 queries. Nevertheles, [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KLtQmtQCkUD) is my attempt to combine the 2 queries together using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/). Please help to confirm whether it is on the right track and advise how we can further proceed to create the full solution.

Comment: We've ended up using the $facet to solve this issue. Many thanks!!!